# Commutativity and Maximal Tori in Connected, Compact Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a path-connected, compact Lie Group.  Let $x \in G$ and let $T_x \subset G$ denote the union of all the maximal tori in $G$ that contain $x$.

Question: Is it true that if $y \notin T_x$, then $xy \neq yx$?

Appreciate everyone's help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for SO(3) where x, y are distinct commuting involutions.

Comment: Right, so, for example, $x = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}$ and $y = \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1}$.  Since $z \in T_x$ implies that $z_{33} = 1$, we have our counter example.  Thanks, studiosus!